# Excel VBA: Which OLE/OCX control to use to display a chart in a form?

Tags: excel, vba, activex, charts, ocx

I have to display a column chart in a user form in VBA. Exporting the chart to GIF and importing in a picture box works; but I cannot use it because the chart needs to be modified based on options chosen by the user from the same form. I have been searching and people have commented that default OLE/OCX controls provided by MS may be used. I cannot find an ActiveX which may do the trick. Does somebody know which controls to use and how to use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use Microsoft Chart, it's the same engine as Microsoft Excel.

Assuming you're using Excel 2003 ... the control is called "Microsoft Office Chart 11.0"

If you have Excel 2007, Microsoft did not ship the chart control. But you can still [download Microsoft Office Chart 11.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=7287252C-402E-4F72-97A5-E0FD290D4B76&displaylang=en). It's in a file called OWC11.EXE.

Then, in the VBA editor, when your VBA UserForm is showing, right click on the toolbox and choose "Additional Controls" and then check "Microsoft Office Chart 11.0" from the list that appears.

Comment: Thanks Joel for the reply :) Somehow, the list of controls I see on clicking "Additional Controls" does not contain "Microsoft Office Chart 11.0". Do I need to import some file to see the control?

Comment: Hmm, maybe that's because I also have Office 2003 installed on this machine :/

Comment: Looks like you can still download it from Microsoft. I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks Joel :) Finally I got the PMs permission to install OWC. I can see the Charts control now.

Comment: If you create a form in Office 2010 using the downloaded chart control, and then open that spreadsheet on a computer that doesn't have the control installed, will the form still work?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this if you just need 2D graphing:

[2D Graph Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ntgraph_activex.aspx)

[3D Graph Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/openGL/ntgraph3d_atl.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Jon :) but I wanted the column charts on my form. This ActiveX control only allows line graphs. Do you know of something which can plot column graphs?

Comment: One of the first ActiveX controls with 3D support was made from my company - Nevron Chart for ActiveX (http://www.nevron.com).

Answer (score 0):

As owner of Gigasoft, please include [Gigasoft's Charting ActiveXs](http://www.gigasoft.com/excelchartactivex.html) within your research.  The above link goes to a complete Excel 2013 walkthrough.  Or see [Access 2013 Charting ActiveX Walkthrough](http://www.gigasoft.com/accesschartactivex.html) for use within Access.

Excel...

[image: activeX chart within Excel]

Access..
[image]